# NSString variable: should it be released?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

When we create NSString object, do I need to release it?

When I run the static analyser for my application, i get the following

```
NSString *dataStr=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];    
Method returns an Objective-C object with a +1 retain count (owning reference)
```

Comment: For your own reference, read up on memory management. Here is a good tutorial: http://mauvilasoftware.com/iphone_software_development/2008/01/iphone-memory-management-a-bri.html

Answer (score 3):

The magic words are `alloc`, `copy`, and `retain`: if any of them are used  when the object is created or the property declared, you will need to `release` it.

Comment: What about `@"string"`? (These questions seem hand-in-hand.

Comment: @"string" is a string with the word *string* in it. When you assign it to a variable, if you ned to use the words `alloc`, `copy`, or `retain` in the process, you will have to later `release` that variable. @"string" by itself really isn't anything until it's assigned to a variable or passed to a method or something.

Comment: `@"string"` is an `NSConstantString` object, you can still do things such as `[@"string" retain]` but it is a no-op for constant strings.

Comment: @dreamlax Fair enough. From the "The OP has limited grasp of Obj-C" perspective, I was just trying to ensure that the question, "What about `@"string"` wasn't coming from an impression that `@"string"` was some other kind of string variable.

Answer (score 3):

The reason the static analyser says that is because your method's name does not imply that the caller of the method has ownership of the object you're returning. There are a few solutions:

1. Modify your method's name so that it implies ownership of the returned object, i.e. these names imply ownership because they start with the word “new” or contain the word “copy”:

   - `- (NSString *) newDataString`
   - `- (NSString *) copyDataString`

   If you use method names like the above, that means that the caller of the method is responsible for sending the object a `release` message when it is done with it.
2. Modify your method so that it relinquishes ownership of the object before returning it using the `autorelease` method:

   ```
   - (NSString *) dataString
   {
       NSString *tmp = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", 2.444];
       return [tmp autorelease];
   }
   ```

   Remember, every `alloc`, `copy` or `retain` *must* be balanced with a `release` or `autorelease` (but not both!).
3. Read the [Cocoa Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html). These rules are not optional, you *must* follow them. The rules are also very simple. After a bit of practice they will become second nature.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to release it.  Generally, any time you create an object pointer calling `alloc` you will need to call `release`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to release it. Every variable which having retain count must be release.